# Interpretation of gradient at a point where it's undefined

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to analyse this function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}+xy$

The gradient it's undefined when $(x,y)=(0,0)$, I'm unsure of what conclusions I can draw from this. By graphing it I see that it's kind of a saddle near $(0,0)$ but it's also really "edgy". Maybe there's a way to prove or refute one or the other without the gradient. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try converting to polar coordinates and seeing what insights that might give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of $g(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a cone and the graph of $h(x,y)=xy$ is a hyperboloid, hence $f(x,y)=g(x,y)+h(x,y)$ is everywhere smooth, except that at the origin. Over the line $x=0$ we have $f(x,y)=|y|$, hence $f$ cannot be differentiable at the origin.

$\hspace{1.5 cm}$[image]